# Calling a function everytime the input text changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<input type="text" onChange="function()">
```

It calls a function everytime the input value change, but to call the function you have to press the enter button or click on something that isn't the input and this is quite annoying. 
Is there a way to call the function everytime the text in the input change? without having to press any button or click out of the input.

Answer (score 3):

Try [**`oninput`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput):

> Unlike `oninput`, the `onchange` event handler is not necessarily called for each alteration to an element's value.

```
<input type="text" oninput="myFunc()">
```

**Please Note:** You also should not use [`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) keyword as your function name.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **keyboard events** to catch `input`field changes

```
    <input type="text" onkeyup="myFunc()">
```

Different keyboard events are

1. *Key up* [`onkeyup`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onkeyup.asp)
2. *Key down* [`onkeydown`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onkeydown.asp)
3. *Key press* [`onkeypress`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onkeypress.asp)